# Need to compose a MySQL query and several SELECT and nested queries

Tags: mysql, select, count, union, nested-select

I need to get a list of the stores that the company has, and I need to output the number of products in each of those stores. The list of stores and items are different tables and I need to merge all of this to output a common answer.
To have all the columns from the stores table and the itemscount column from the items table. So far I have this query, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items 
WHERE store_name = (SELECT storename FROM stores 
WHERE companyid = (SELECT id FROM companies 
WHERE clientmail = ''email'))) AS itemcount FROM stores
WHERE companyid = (SELECT id FROM companies 
WHERE clientmail = 'email');
```

I also tried this request, but it was wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM stores 
WHERE companyid = (SELECT id FROM companies WHERE clientmail = 'email')
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) AS itemscount FROM items 
WHERE store_name = (SELECT storename FROM stores 
WHERE companyid = (SELECT id FROM companies WHERE clientmail = 'email'));
```

I would like to get a complex sample from a query that accesses different tables and compounds the answers in one sample

Comment: are you alowed to use join queries? can you give a sample of tables structure, DDL for example !!

Comment: You should use a `JOIN` for this, not correllated subqueries - _especially_ not ones 5 levels deep, erk.